# Laravel Spark plan based on user property

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-spark

I am currently using laravel spark for stripe v5.0.

I have setup 2 plans

1. male plan with $10
2. female plan with $5

On the /billing page, my application users based on their gender who are male should see only one plan to subscribe to which is $10 and female users should be able to see only one plan to subscribe to which is $5.

how can I conditionally show them plans based on such User model property?

Comment: Show the part of blade view template code where is that rendered.

Comment: The view is not a custom view, the view comes from the spark vendor itself. I could not find a way to override this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Putting this into the template only sounds like a bad idea

Comment: @NicoHaase I just thought to check gender over `$user` object and conditionally to show the line. I am certain `$user` object would be in that part of template. Nothing wrong with that I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer to this:

We will be able to achieve this in the resolve closure inside SparkServiceProvider like follows:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    Spark::billable(User::class)->resolve(function (Request $request) {

     app('config')->set(
        'spark.billables.user.plans',
        [
            [
                'name'              => $request()->user()->plan->name,
                'short_description' => 'Only 1 user access',
                'monthly_id'        => 'price_id',
                'features'          => [
                    'Single Person Access',
                    'Monthly Subscription',
                    'Automatic Renewal',
                ],
                'options'           => [
                    'uk'     => true,
                    'others' => false,
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );

    return $request->user();

    });
}
```